# windows server 2012 r2 change node type

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012-r2, wins

I'd like to force a station to be Node Type *p-mode* instead of *hybrid*.

In regedit: `cptr\HLMCurrentControlSet\Services\NetBT\Parameters` I don't find the node mode.

The goal is to remove UDP port 138 packets sent by each node to the broadcast domain about every 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your registry key path is a little off, check for the `DHCPNodeType` value in the following key:

`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NetBT\Parameters`

You'll likely need to change the value from the default of `0x8` to `0x2`.

Reference: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781175(v=ws.10).aspx

The documentation reference is for Server 2003 but I just verified that the key/value are present in the same location in Server 2012 R2.

Comment: The DHCPNodeType key is not present in my case. Maybe because no WINS server is configured yet, or because the server is configured statically (no dhcp) maybe?

Comment: No, the server I checked is configured statically with no WINS servers defined. You should be able to add the value as a `REG_DWORD` using the referenced documentation.